# Is there any shortcut to make css positioning programmatic instead of declarative?

Tags: javascript, css

How complicated will it be to implement from scratch?

Mainly for layout issues.

The reason I want to make it declarative is that I hope to encapsulate it into a javascript class,so that I don't need to cope with css deficits once and again,instead,once for all.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are talking about layout issues you are currently face because of css deficits. Could you grant us some inside in what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I agree with merkuro. You would probably be better served with a CSS meta-language like Sass (to name just one) rather than doing everything with Javascript.

Comment: The reason I want to make it declarative is that I hope to encapsulate it into a class,so that I don't need to cope with css deficits once and again,instead,once for all.

Comment: I'd suggest you check out JSON CSS, Shore. See my response below for more details.

Comment: There are other languages that make up for CSS' deficiencies without having the horrible deficiencies of JavaScript. You should really use one of those.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a big deal at all.  You just do things like

```
document.getElementById('whatever').style.width = 100;
```

or, in jQuery,

```
$('#whatever').css('width', 100);
```

Gotta say, though, it sounds like you want to completely replace stylesheets with programmatic style manipulation, and that's probably a terrible idea.

Comment: Yes,what I'm asking about is the terrible version:)

Comment: Well the question was tagged "JavaScript", so I hope he knows the implications of doing such a thing, but I agree, completely replacing CSS with JavaScript is a terrible idea.

Comment: Yeah, your Web site will look like crap for anyone running noscript.

Comment: Not to mention the initial render probably being a mass of craziness until the programmatic styles are done being applied.

Comment: Your comments are all reasonable,but layout is my biggest headache,so I want to find a way to fix it once and never need to cope with it again.

Comment: If your site requires Javascript to operate completely, then I don't see any reason to avoid CSSJSON, or some other method of styles-by-script.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, the only correct answer here is **don't do it - learn CSS properly**. You seem to want to get around some deficiencies in CSS, but you don't say what they are, apart from "layout" which is about as vague as you can get. CSS does layout fine (using floats, not positioning - the latter is rarely used for layout).

Setting CSS styles using Javascript isn't really solving any problem as far as I can see. Maybe you need to explain more clearly (with examples) what your problem is.

Comment: Floats certainly can't produce all types of layout that a person might want.

Comment: @ilya n - No, but most layouts that people might want can be acheived through floats.

Comment: @ilya: what layouts can't be achieved through CSS alone? (I'm sure you're correct but I can't think of anything.) And how is JS going to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should clarify your question. If I understand it is as "Why is it that CSS is a declarative language rather then imperative" then it's because it's conceptually closer to how humans want webpages to be styled (and how browsers feel comfortable reading it).

Comment: Or, to make a nice layout, use one of the standard ones around the web.

Comment: Well, you can use jQuery as in the example to modify your page to your liking, and encapsulate it into your object... anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Check out **JSON CSS**. It's a rather interesting method of using the power of Javascript (performing logic, etc) in a nice and orderly fashion to set styles. Arc90.Labs has a nice write-up on the topic with examples.

http://lab.arc90.com/2009/01/json_css.php (also on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/jsoncss/))

Demo JSON CSS Stylesheet:

```
{
    "@variables": {
        "demoBgColor": "#FBFAF4"
    },

    "#demoContainer": {
        "background-color": "@{demoBgColor}",
        "border": "1px dotted #CCC",
        "padding": "0.5em",
        "width": "40em",
        "@browser[msie-6]": {
            "width": "400px"
        },

        "h3.header": {
            "text-decoration": "underline"
        },

        "div:first": {
            "font-weight": "bold"
        }
    }
}
```